# Stop Webstorm of Displaying Error on hbs! Plugin for require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, webstorm, require-handlebars

There are two files in my project:

- index.js where the following code is

  define([ 'exports', 'hbs!./general'], function (exports, generalTemplate) {
  });
- general.handlebars which is correctly taken by require.js and the `hbs!` plug-in.

I'm basically using Require.js with Handlebars.js and the https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin for automating the creation of templates from files.

It works correctly, but Webstorm 8 (and also 7 before it) doesn't understand the file is correct so it always complains with: **Cannot resolve file 'general'**. It is the same with every file using that plugin prefix.

I coudln't find where (if it exists) to turn that notification off, because it underlines the entire file, and its parent directories as having errors.

How can I remove this error of being reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notification can't be turned off unfortunately - annotator-level inspections can't be suppressed.
The issue with relative paths resolving when loading plugins for non-js extensions is tracked as [WEB-1167](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1167), please vote